# Image overlay HTM/CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, overlay

I am looking for a solution to get an overlay like the image below using HTML/CSS or jQuery or any other solution.

I want to use it on my website as an overlay for a background image.

The overlay:
[Image](http://i61.tinypic.com/14o3c3k.png)

Comment: You want it to be the background for your website?

Comment: Yes, or anyway will do I just need to know how to get the overlay done.

Comment: What do you mean by overlay? The picture of the car thing?

Comment: I think he want to use the dotted image over his background image or order to create the same effect, like I did in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/M34JL/2/show/ with `divs` (using lines instead of dots), but I *may be wrong*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set that as the background for your website, it's as simple as writing it in the CSS file as:

```
html {
    background-image: url(http://oi61.tinypic.com/14o3c3k.jpg)
}
```

or setting it via jQuery (you tagged your question with jQuery, so I assume you want to know how to do it that way)

```
$("body").parent().css("background-image", "url(" + http://oi61.tinypic.com/14o3c3k.jpg + ")")
//you can also use $("html")… I've just seen cases where that failed for people
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but the problem is to have a black dotted overlay. Is there anyway to do this in HTML/CSS or is this a Photoshop matter?

Comment: I think the question was more about how to combine an overlay to an existing background. I think the OP has some clean images they'd rather not edit manually.

Comment: I want the black dots over another image.

Comment: @JoeriSmits I don't know of any library that lets you edit pictures like that client-side. Either way, it'd be a really slow process. It'd be better to just do it before putting it on your server.

Comment: @JoeriSmits Actually, if you can produce an image of just the black dots, you can easily set its opacity to an amount that will let you layer it over the other picture. The key would be to make a PNG file that is transparent (other than the black dots).

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, however I found a website with a video behind it so it should be possible.Link to the website: http://cloudcoderz.com/

Comment: @JoeriSmits Yeah, they've just set the opacity to an amount that allows you to see the video behind. The foreground is really just a tessellated image of black dots.

Answer (score 1):

To recreate the same effect as in the picture you can use a little `2 x 2` pixels PNG image that has 3 transparent pixels and 1 fully opaque black pixel (You *can* use the image that I've used in the following code). Then you put this image in a `div` that will overlay the background image and apply transparency to it (the overlay image):

**Here's the CSS:**

```
* {
    margin:0;
}
html, body {
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/TBaaZJC.png");
}
.overlay {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:0.25;
    background:url("http://i.imgur.com/pVNSmP4.png");
}
```

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/E5DAN/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```css
* {
    margin:0;
}
body {
    background:url("http://www.conceptcarz.com/images/Citroen/2010-Citroen-Survolt-Concept-Image-01.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
}
.bg-transparent {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40)
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-transparent"></div>
```

Here you can find a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/erasad22/evc8x9hk/